# Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, openid

I'm using this template: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef

And get the following error: Validation of viewstate MAC failed.. Web farm..

There are a lot of people with this problem and (the best?) suggestion I found was to update web.config with a machine key (as the site is at a web farm):

```
  <machineKey validation="SHA1" validationKey=""
decryption="Auto" decryptionKey="" />
```

however now I get this error:

```
Unable to validate data.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to validate data.

Source Error:

Line 6:  <head>
Line 7:     <title>Login</title>
Line 8:     <%= Html.OpenIdSelectorStyles(this.Page) %>
Line 9:     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%= Url.Content("~/Content/loginpopup.css") %>' />
Line 10: </head>


Source File:    Line: 8

Stack TraceWhy is this and how do I fix it?
```

Thanks
M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space in your validation key, remove it.

You also want to be careful not to use a machine key you've found online as it's used as the encryption key for your cookies.  Using one found online, especially on a well known site makes it easier to compromise your site.  You can find some code to generate a key at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312906.

Comment: Yes that worked very nice, however when I use the console application that you recommended I get this error: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: So it works when I remove the space but it stops working when i try to replace the key with my newly generated

Comment: If you're changing machine keys, any old cookie is going to throw that error since it can't be decrypted by the new key.  Try deleting your cookies for your site and see if the error goes away.